# Where can I find the Call Stack in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Embarrassingly I cannot find the Call Stack window in VS 2017. I've tried using the path of (menu) Debug> Windows> Call Stack that was used in Visual Studio 2015.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 43):

The menu option only appears while debugging, it should be where you're looking for it:

[image]

[image]

Compared to while not debugging:

[image]